# how to receieve nagios info in c# event handler parameters. like in shell scripts

Tags: c#, nagios

In this article http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/eventhandlers.html#example they show how to get arguments from nagios to shell script. I have done this. Now in this article they show how to receive nagios parameters in .bat files. You can access nagios parameters like so:
(::echo 1: %1    2: %2    3: %3    4: %4)

In shell script  I would access the variables like this: echo $1, echo $2 ect...

How do I access this variables in c# in .exe file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Nagios just passes the arguments via command line. Assuming your C# project is just a console application, the command line arguments will be passed to `Main`. So the following will print 3 arguments:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args[0]);     // echo $1
        Console.WriteLine(args[1]);     // echo $2
        Console.WriteLine(args[2]);     // echo $3
    }
}
```

Note, before retrieving the command line arguments make sure to check that the indices are valid.

Comment: Ok I suspected as much. I will give it a try and if it works that will unleash such great control!

Comment: just wanted to mention foreach(var x in args){Console.WriteLine(x);} will do as well.